# using tastypie to create and update models

Tags: django, tastypie

I am using tastypie to quickly create an api for my django project. My Django consists of some Models, one of them is a customer model. The customer model has a foreign key to django's user model so it looks like this

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...fields....
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_customers'
```

I have created my CustomerResource

```
class CustomerResourse(ModelResource):
    creator = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource,'creator', null = True,
        blank= True, full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'last_name':ALL,
            'first_name':ALL,
    }
        resource_name = 'customer'
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
```

I woul like to be able to update my model using the api. Reading the tutorial it says updating a model is using PUT. So my steps were.

1) Log in and get sessionid
2)store it
3)get the resource i need
4)modify the resource i need
5)create headers
6)use requests.put to put data back passing the headers and the sessionid cookie.

the code(using requests)

```
headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
resp = requets.post(login_url, data=credentials, headers=headers)
sessionid = resp.cookies['sessionid']
cookies = {'sessionid':sessionid}
customer_json = request.get(customer_resource_url, cookies=cookies)
customer_json['mobile'] = 'new mobile'
resp.put(customer_resource_url, data=data, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

What i get is a 401 unauthorized status code though. The user is super and staff so he can modify everything. The login happens normaly and I get the sessionid as i should.

And a second question. If i create a new customer, will tastypie take care of foreign keys e.g taking in consideration the sessionid to determine the user creator, or does it need to be done manualy?

Comment: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html it says here that for session authentication you need to have a valid csrf token .. set this in your header X-CSRFToken:token_value

Comment: How do i get a valid token?And how come it worked on my login function?(post method again)

Comment: is there a better way to create a client to authenticate with django?Any good tutorials on that better way?

Comment: How will i get my csrf token from my tastypie api calls(urls)?When i use get on an api url it doesn't have csrftoken in the cookies

Comment: Guess i can't use tastypie...noone can help